# Why are all elements in the mobile-nav ul showing on top of each other?

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

I have the following problem: When I use absolute positioning for the `#mobile-nav-content` container for my mobile menu, the  elements of the `ul` in it are appearing top of each other.

I want them to be stacked under each other with `background-color:grey;` (They do not need to be hidden, I will work on that part later).

I want the elements of the ul to be over each other and the background color to be BLACK.

This is my code, what do I need to change to get this to work?

```css
/*===FARBEN===
BLAU:#1F4E8C
GRAU:#3D3F45
HELLGRAU: #E5E5E5
ROT: #A62C21
*/

/* GLOBAL */
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Raleway', 'Lato', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size:16px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* GENERELLES */

.clearfix::after{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

/*===NAVIGATIONSLEISTE===*/

.header-nav{
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  background-color:#3d3f45;
  position:relative;
  font-size:25px;
  font-weight:bold;
}
.header-nav a>img{
  position:absolute;
  height:30px;
  width:auto;
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
}
.header-nav ul>li{
  display:inline-block;
  height:100%;
}

.header-nav ul{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  right:10px;
}
.header-nav ul>li>a{
  display:inline-block;
  margin-top:10px;
}

.header-nav ul>li>a:link{color:black;text-decoration:none;}
.header-nav ul>li>a:hover{color:black;text-decoration:none;}
.header-nav ul>li>a:active{color:black;text-decoration:none;}
.header-nav ul>li>a:visited{color:black;text-decoration:none;}

#active{
  background-color:#A62C21;
}

/* MOBILES NAVIGATIONSMENÜ */

#mobile-nav-dropdown{
  position:relative;
}

#mobile-nav-content{
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:50px;
}


#mobile-nav-button{
  color:white;
  float:right;
  font-size:30px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  padding-left:9px;
  padding-right:9px;
  margin-top:5px;
  margin-right:5px;

}
#mobile-nav-content>ul>li{
  display:block;
  background-color:#3D3F45;
  padding-left:20px;
  padding-right:20px;
}
#mobile-nav-content>ul{
  margin-right:40px;
}

/* HEADER-BANNER */
#header-banner{
  background: url("../img/hintergrund.jpg") no-repeat;
  width:100%
  height:0;
  padding-top:20.83%;
  background-size:contain;
}
#header-banner-klein{
  background: url("../img/hintergrund-klein.jpg") no-repeat;
  width:100%
  height:0;
  padding-top:15.625%;
  background-size:contain;
}
/* GRID SYSTEM */

.container{
  width:95%;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}

.row::after{
  content:"";
  clear:both;
  display:block;
  border: 0 !important;
}
[class*="col-"]{
  float:left;
  padding:10px;
}

.col-1{width:16.6666%;}
.col-2{width:33.3333%;}
.col-3{width:50%;     }
.col-6{width:100%;    }

 /* GRID SYSTEM SICHTBARKEIT
.container,.container *{
border:1px solid #91c4ff;
}

[class*="col-"]{
  background-color:#bfddff;
}
p {background-color:#91c4ff;
padding:0;
margin:0;
color:#fff;
text-align:center;
} */

/* Responsive Design */
@media(max-width:768px){
  .col-1{width:33.3333%;}
  .col-2{width:50%;}
  .col-3{width:100%;}
}
@media(max-width:480px){
  .col-1{width:50%;}
  .col-2{width:100%;}
  .col-3{width:100%;}
}

/* GRID SYSTEM FIX */

.header-nav *{
  padding:0;
  border:0;
}

.header-nav .container{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Startseite</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/css/styles.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- NAVIGATIONSLEISTE -->
    <nav class="header-nav">

      <!-- <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6">
            <a href="index.html">
              <img src="src/img/webdesign-logo.png">
            </a>
            <ul>
              <li id="active"><a href="index.html">Startseite</a></li>
              <li><a href="Leistungen.html">Leistungen</a></li>
              <li><a href="Kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
              <li><a href="Impressum.html">Impressum</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> -->
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6 clearfix">
            <a href="index.html">
              <img src="src/img/webdesign-logo.png">
            </a>

            <div id="mobile-nav-dropdown" class="clearfix">

              <div id="mobile-nav-button">&equiv;</div>

              <div id="mobile-nav-content" class="clearfix">

                <ul>
                  <li id="active"><a href="index.html">Startseite</a></li>
                  <li><a href="Leistungen.html">Leistungen</a></li>
                  <li><a href="Kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
                  <li><a href="Impressum.html">Impressum</a></li>
                </ul>

              </div>

            </div>



          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- HEADER-BANNER -->
  <header id="header-banner"></header>


  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear - firstly there is no `header-nav-content` element in your code. Also, you haven't explained what exactly you want help with  - do you just want help in stacking them one under the next? Or are are you also looking for help with making it show and hide too? In that case, you have no code included for attempting this, or any indication of how it should work (CSS? JS? On clack or on hover? etc) so we cannot help you without more information.

Comment: sorry i meant mobile-nav-content. i just want help stacking it on each other,.

Comment: I've added an answer, but I'm confused when you say "*i Want them to be under each other with background-color:grey;. please can you help me? I want the elements of the ul to be over each other and the background color to be BLACK.*" - do you want the background to be grey or black?

Comment: Doesn't matter. Just so it is visible.

Comment: I can change it myself then. I'm not that bad in coding

Comment: Well, its grey in my answer below anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You are very close with the code you have, you just need to make one change. The problem is being caused by `height:100%` in your `.header-nav ul` CSS. What this does is take 100% of the container height (i.e. `#mobile-nav-dropdown` ), but for this to work the container must have been given a specific height.

In this case, we don't want to give the nav dropdown and ul a specific height, but instead to be `auto` so it will be the height it needs to accommodate its contents. So you just need to change the `height` in `.header-nav ul` to `auto`:

```
.header-nav ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:absolute;
    right:10px;
    /* Change height from 100% to auto (or remove it altogether as auto is the default value ) */
    height:auto;
}
```

When you start working on the code to show/hide the menu, this should work with it!

**Working Example:**

```css
/*===FARBEN===
BLAU:#1F4E8C
GRAU:#3D3F45
HELLGRAU: #E5E5E5
ROT: #A62C21
*/

/* GLOBAL */
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Raleway', 'Lato', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size:16px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* GENERELLES */

.clearfix::after{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

/*===NAVIGATIONSLEISTE===*/

.header-nav{
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  background-color:#3d3f45;
  position:relative;
  font-size:25px;
  font-weight:bold;
}
.header-nav a>img{
  position:absolute;
  height:30px;
  width:auto;
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
}
.header-nav ul>li{
  display:inline-block;
  height:100%;
}

.header-nav ul{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  position:absolute;
  height:auto;
  right:10px;
}

.header-nav ul>li>a{
  display:inline-block;
  margin-top:10px;
}

.header-nav ul>li>a:link{color:black;text-decoration:none;}
.header-nav ul>li>a:hover{color:black;text-decoration:none;}
.header-nav ul>li>a:active{color:black;text-decoration:none;}
.header-nav ul>li>a:visited{color:black;text-decoration:none;}

#active{
  background-color:#A62C21;
}

/* MOBILES NAVIGATIONSMENÜ */

#mobile-nav-dropdown{
  position:relative;
}

#mobile-nav-content{
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:50px;
}


#mobile-nav-button{
  color:white;
  float:right;
  font-size:30px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  padding-left:9px;
  padding-right:9px;
  margin-top:5px;
  margin-right:5px;

}
#mobile-nav-content>ul>li{
  display:block;
  background-color:#3D3F45;
  padding-left:20px;
  padding-right:20px;
}
#mobile-nav-content>ul{
  margin-right:40px;
}

/* HEADER-BANNER */
#header-banner{
  background: url("../img/hintergrund.jpg") no-repeat;
  width:100%
  height:0;
  padding-top:20.83%;
  background-size:contain;
}
#header-banner-klein{
  background: url("../img/hintergrund-klein.jpg") no-repeat;
  width:100%
  height:0;
  padding-top:15.625%;
  background-size:contain;
}
/* GRID SYSTEM */

.container{
  width:95%;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}

.row::after{
  content:"";
  clear:both;
  display:block;
  border: 0 !important;
}
[class*="col-"]{
  float:left;
  padding:10px;
}

.col-1{width:16.6666%;}
.col-2{width:33.3333%;}
.col-3{width:50%;     }
.col-6{width:100%;    }

 /* GRID SYSTEM SICHTBARKEIT
.container,.container *{
border:1px solid #91c4ff;
}

[class*="col-"]{
  background-color:#bfddff;
}
p {background-color:#91c4ff;
padding:0;
margin:0;
color:#fff;
text-align:center;
} */

/* Responsive Design */
@media(max-width:768px){
  .col-1{width:33.3333%;}
  .col-2{width:50%;}
  .col-3{width:100%;}
}
@media(max-width:480px){
  .col-1{width:50%;}
  .col-2{width:100%;}
  .col-3{width:100%;}
}

/* GRID SYSTEM FIX */

.header-nav *{
  padding:0;
  border:0;
}

.header-nav .container{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Startseite</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/css/styles.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- NAVIGATIONSLEISTE -->
    <nav class="header-nav">

      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6 clearfix">
            <a href="index.html">
              <img src="src/img/webdesign-logo.png">
            </a>

            <div id="mobile-nav-dropdown" class="clearfix">

              <div id="mobile-nav-button">&equiv;</div>

              <div id="mobile-nav-content" class="clearfix">

                <ul>
                  <li id="active"><a href="index.html">Startseite</a></li>
                  <li><a href="Leistungen.html">Leistungen</a></li>
                  <li><a href="Kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
                  <li><a href="Impressum.html">Impressum</a></li>
                </ul>

              </div>

            </div>



          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- HEADER-BANNER -->
  <header id="header-banner"></header>


  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: @NoBody Glad it worked! If this answer was helpful, you could consider accepting it by clicking the grey checkmark beside it. This marks the question as resolved on the site and lets other users with similar questions know that you found it helpful. Plus you get a few rep points :)